# Ruby on Rails Ajax request doesn't appear without page update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've built an app in Rails with tables posts and articles. The idea is when I'm at posts's page I can view all comments related to this post and add new comments. New comments appear at the page immediately after adding, w/o page update. The issue is that when I create the comments via ajax, they don't appear at the page - I need to update it. And I don't understand why this is happening

**create.js.erb**

```
var new_comment = $("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment))%>").hide();
$('#comments').prepend(new_comment);
$('#comment_<%= @comment.id %>').fadeIn('slow');
$('#new_comment')[0].reset();
```

**my post show page is**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>

 <h2>Comments</h2>
 <div id="comments">    
    <%= render :partial => @post.comments.reverse %>
</div>

<%= form_for([@post, Comment.new], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.label :body, "New Comment" %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Add Comment" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

**my create action for comment is**

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
        format.js #create.js.erb
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and my _comment.html.erb file

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
      <p>
        <strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></strong><br />
        <%= h(comment.body) %>
      </P>
    <% end %>
```

Could you please help me find out where the problem can be?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What response do you get from the ajax (if you check firebug or chrome dev tools)

Comment: When I press "Add comment" - I see POST request and it's ok. Then after "refresh" I get several GET requests, partly OK and partly with 304 "Not modified" error, they also have cache-control field "no cache"... if this helps... Or what exactly should I look for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess my previous answer wasn't what you were asking me. Because when I don't use ajax I get the same portion of GET requests, some of them are OK, some has the same error. The difference is after pressing "add comment" POST and GET requests are generated "automatically" together, w/o refresh

Comment: 304 code is not an error, is a cache status that indicates that the page has loaded from local cache...

Comment: Yeah 304 is good. You just have to then look for the response body, which should be javascript.

Comment: I looked more carefully at my response

`Set-Cookies: "request_method=POST; path=/_blog_session=OUM1TFdLNDdLR3R6cU5aekl1c0Q0ZHoxdDF2Y2hWRGRsa2F4SjluNFZvdDIxQUl6cm9hQ0NINHVadkNIcG9ETldXSXNQd1pDRXk5ZGxRQXdUZ0tnU05iSGdRODN4b3hrUTNFZ0lmeERiaTlIdTdCcGxNelN5Qmo3RHdKKzd6MkttYUg5L3RIY1Zpc3E1MW9KVklqcXpBPT0tLTdObHhhT1c1OStCRC8vT3J5NkIxOXc9PQ%3D%3D--895d159a58cd8c10a3727a084b169a4d27308e1a; path=/; **HttpOnly**"`

This "HttpOnly" - can it be any settings of my browser that don't let me to send and process Ajax request?

Comment: I also have

`Content-type "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"`

`X-content-type-options "nosniff"`

`X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"`

Comment: And I have one more question - if I delete at all create.js.erb file and send an Ajax request - I'll get an error because my browser doesn't know how to process such request. But if then I refresh the page - the new comment will be added! Why is it happening?
Consequently, with create.js.erb file - the fact that page update let me see my new comment, doesn't mean that the problem is in it's representation. May be it wasn't created at all...

Answer (score 0):

I found the misprint in post show page - was written "commetns" instead of "comments". Now everything works as it should
@jphager2, thank you for your help